# How to combine Widgets in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to merge two widgets that show on the same row (left and right) the template is build to host text on the left and a gravity form on the right. I want instead a full width area without splitting the row in two columns.

The template does this (nasty imo) also in other areas but has some pros that I wish to preserve. How hard would be to turn it into a full width area (1 widget) and what steps should I follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would create a child theme and then overwrite the template that is being used to create the widget area. You should also disable the widget location that you are removing so that it isn't shown in the admin. You can use the following code to remove the widget area.

```
function remove_some_widgets(){
    unregister_sidebar( 'first-footer-widget-area' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'remove_some_widgets', 11 );
```

You would replace 'first-footer-widget-area' with the identifier for the widget area you are removing.

I can't give a code example for combining the widget areas because it would depend on the code available in your theme. In case you don't have a child theme, here is a link for how to create one: https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Comment: hello, the theme I'm altering is already a child theme (of Genesis) I think that I have to alter the front-page.php file along with relative CSS can you please confirm?

Comment: I can't confirm because I don't have the code available and am not that familiar with Genesis. That being said you could update the area you think is correct with some text and if that text appears in the right spot you know you are on the right track.